# Php selecting one of each kind

Tags: php, mysql

For example i have lots of users, each of them has selected the game they like, now in the same mysql row they have recommends (thumbs up).
Example Database:

> (nickname): Leonard, (recommends): 999, (game): Mario; (nickname):
>   Nikky, (recommends): 1999, (game): Counter-Strike (nickname): Sam,
>   (recommends): 199, (game): AION

Now what i want to do is select the most recommended user for each game without doing double mysql requests, is that possible?

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY recommends DESC

This is just showing all of them sorted by the recommends amount but what i want is to show 1 with the most recommends for each game because there are many users that have bunch of recommends for the same game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: MySQL 5.7

Despite being accepted, in the original response (see below) the proposed code with MySQL 5.6 does not produce the desired result, and from MySQL 5.7 it is not executable.

I recommend this approach instead:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM users a 
LEFT JOIN users b 
ON a.game = b.game AND a.recommends < b.recommends
WHERE b.recommends IS NULL;
```

By performing a `LEFT_JOIN` between `a` and `b` when `a.game` is equal to `b.game` and `a.recommends` is less than `b.recommends` we obtain a set in which higher values of `a.recommends` are associated with null values of `b.recommends`. Something like this:

```
a.nickname  a.recommends  a.game     b.recommends
----------  ------------  ---------  ------------
will        100           mariobros  110
mary        50            cart       80
john        110           mariobros  800
will        100           mariobros  800
martin      80            cart       null
viola       800           mariobros  null
```

With `WHERE b.recommends IS NULL` we restrict the selection to the rows we are interested in. This way if there are two nicknames with the same score in the same category they are both selected, which was not the case in the previous code.

<kbd>**[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/saRuWRHA)**</kbd>

---

### Original Answer:

You can simply prepend `GROUP BY` to `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY game ORDER BY recommends DESC
```

<kbd>**[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/688e3e9/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! thats really easy and simplest way to do it, plus love the way that u used sqlfiddie

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause to combine multiple records based on one column, and `COUNT()` to count. Hard without seeing your full schema, but something like:

`SELECT users.*, COUNT(users.recommends) AS total_recommends FROM users ORDER BY recommends DESC GROUP BY game`

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by.

```
SELECT users.*, MAX(user.recommends) AS maxrec GROUP BY game;
```

Comment: Pretty sure MySQL expects `GROUP BY` to appear after `ORDER BY` in queries, no?

Comment: When thinking about it, I don't remember. It's been a little while since I used MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM users AS t1
LEFT JOIN users AS t2
ON t1.game = t2.game AND t1.recommends < t2.recommends
WHERE t2.recommends IS NULL
```

Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43486/13/0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, it seems that you want is :

```
SELECT * FROM users group by game ORDER BY recommends DESC
```

`group by` makes that only one user per game is retrieved and `order by` retrieves the user with the high score.